# Why extending an Interface does not make it's method to return more precise types?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

For example if we have a class `Person` and a class `Student` extends Person.
The we may have:

```
public interface PersonQueryBuilder<T extends Person> {
    PersonQueryBuilder<T> withName(String name);

    PersonQueryBuilder<T> withAgeBetween(int from, int to);

    List<T> getResultList();
}

public interface StudentRepository<T extends Student> extends PersonQueryBuilder<T> {
    StudentRepository studying(Course course);
}
```

So why when I have an StudentRepository, both the withName() and withAgeBetween() methods return a PersonQueryBuilder and not and StudentRepository? This is very annoying. Is there any "elegant" way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of funny. I propose the following (ugly?) solution that doesn't require you to redefine the methods in the interface as Mark's answer does:

```
interface PersonQueryBuilder<T extends Person, U extends PersonQueryBuilder<T,U>> {
    U withName(String name);

    U withAgeBetween(int from, int to);
}

interface StudentRepository extends PersonQueryBuilder<Student, StudentRepository> {
    StudentRepository studying(Course course);
}
```

Also you're using raw types as results in your current implementations of your `with` methods.

Comment: I was actually going to tack this on but I got turned off by all the recursive types :-).  It's a viable solution though.

Comment: Actually the more I think about it the more I think this is the preferred solution, or would definitely be if we were dealing with classes and not interfaces.  With interfaces, it's pretty cheap to redeclare using covariance.  At the class level you have to *redefine* and that's a lot more expensive.  You're simply adding a type parameter that specifies what type your class produces.  The fact that it's the same of the class is just a special case and actually isn't enforced.

Comment: @Mark: Sure. This opens the possibility of having a `QueryBuilder` that returns something else. I have absolutely no idea whether this might be useful. ;) Otoh, in the case of redeclaring it's the same as with a type parameter: You could return any type that is a subtype of `PersonQueryBuilder` and not just the type that defines it.

Answer (score 4):

```
interface StudentRepository<T extends Student> extends PersonQueryBuilder<T> {
   StudentRepository<T> studying(Course course);
   StudentRepository<T> withName(String name);
   StudentRepository<T> withAgeBetween(int from, int to);
}
```

You can redeclare the methods in the sub-interface.  Implementors of `StudentRepository` will now be required to return a `StudentRepository` for those methods, but the implementation can still be used polymorphically as a `PersonQueryBuilder`.

Comment: This is called "covariant return types"

Comment: @Jim: that's right, and I should note I think it's only available in Java 1.5+.  But that shouldn't be a problem for someone using Generics obviously.

Answer (score 2):

For one, because you use the raw type PersonQueryBuilder as return type. `T` does not appear in this type, so why should a particular `T` matter? A first improvement therefore is:

```
PersonQueryBuilder<T> withName(String name);

PersonQueryBuilder<T> withAgeBetween(int from, int to);
```

The next problem stems from that a StudentRepository need not be the only PersonQueryBuilder for Students, as it would be entirely legal to declare:

```
interface UniversityRepository<T extends Student> extends PersonQueryBuilder<T> { }
```

So by your logic, should the return type be StudentRepository or UniversityRepository? Or somehow both? The compiler can't know your intention, so must specify what you want, for instance by using a covariant return type:

```
public interface StudentRepository<T extends Student> extends PersonQueryBuilder<T> {
    @Override
    StudentRepository<T> withName(String name);

    @Override
    StudentRepository<T> withAgeBetween(int from, int to);

    StudentRepository<T> studying(Course course);
}
```

The obvious disadvantage of that approach is that you have to repeat all inherited methods. You can get around this with a type parameter for the actual repository:

```
public interface PersonQueryBuilder<T extends Person, R extends PersonQueryBuilder<T, R>> {
    R withName(String name);

    R withAgeBetween(int from, int to);

    List<T> getResultList();
}
```

and

```
public interface StudentRepository<T extends Student, R extends StudentRepository<T, R> extends PersonQueryBuilder<T, R> {
    R studying(Course course);
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using this approach but I don't really like it. Is better than redefine all the methods but I thought that might be a better way. Why the compiler can't do this for me?